# Best book for learning multiple integrals, line integrals, Green's theorem, etc.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, book-recommendation, volume, surfaces

I've been searching for a book that teaches multiple integrals and such in a way that I can understand. I need to learn it quickly, so I don't need too much of the intuition, I just need to be able to do the mechanics of it in an exam. I also learn well with lots of worked examples.

Can someone recommend a few books? Thanks.

Comment: I also wonder what book should I use to understand contour integral. I hope your post gets a good answer.

Comment: “I don’t need too much of the intuition, I just need to be able to do the mechanics if it in an exam.” I feel the need to comment here that this is a miserable way to learn math.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the last third of Swokowski.  [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000Z69RRQ) is the edition I know.

Even better would be a Schaum's Outline, but I'm not sure if there is one that is exactly the "Calc 3" which you are requesting.  Look at Vector analysis and Advanced Calculus.  Older editions usually better content.  Old hardcopy usually better than digital scan or reprint.

P.s. for Stack police, I am aware the question is old.  But answer will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I neither work for the authors nor Amazon.

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538497815) by Stewart should be ok. It's a big, broad book but so are your goals. Multiple integrals + curvilinear integrals + Green's Theorem in such a short time is a heavy task, though doable.

It's super intuitive, has great examples and summaries to learn the mechanics.

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387909745) lacks the exuberance of Stewart's but should work for you as well.